# Monitor mongodb replica sets

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, replication

I have a cluster environment and I have two shard replica sets and 1 configured replication set is configured when I have run the command `db.stats()` so why does it always show data set to shard replication?

I need to collect config replica set data, because it mentions above 3.2+, you can deploy the config  as replication set and I did the same.

Please help me find the exact command or I am doing something wrong because I need to monitor configuration replication set data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the config of replica set, you can find it by `rs.conf()` or `rs.config()`.

You can find out more about replication command [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replication/)

But if you want to check the data inside the replication, you have to login to replication node by `rs.slaveOk()`, before do some queries.

PS. Sorry if I get your question wrong...